# Vector-Valued Functions and When They are Equal (whatever that means)

Tags: calculus

Say I have two vector-valued functions 
$ \vec{r} = sin(t)\vec{i} + cos(t)\vec{j}$ and $\vec{r} = sin(t^2)\vec{i} + cos(t^2)\vec{j}$ . They both trace out a unit circle but their curves aren't equal. How is this? What i'm really asking is how does one tell when two different vector-valued functions have the same and when they have different curves. And what would it mean when two vector-valued functions are equal (if they can ever be) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, two functions have the same curves if $f(t) = g(t)$ for all $t$. That's a much stronger requirement than their *images* being equal, i.e. than $\{f(t)\,:\, t \in \mathbb{R}\} = \{g(t)\,:\, t \in \mathbb{R}\}$.

Which of the two definitions of *equality* makes more sense depends on the context. If you're interested in $f$ and $g$ as *functions*, you'll usually only considerm them equal of $f(t)=g(t)$ for all $t$. If, however, you're using $f$ and $g$ as parametrizations of some geometric object, you might not care whether they are equal for every parameter value, but only whether they create the same object or not.